# How the promise is getting reolved in Protractor for the filter function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, protractor

I am using the below function in protractor which uses a filter function. Here **let requiredArtifacts**
is declared and it will be the return value of the filter function once the filter promise gets resolved.
That means when i run this fuction, **let loc = requiredArtifacts.getLocation();** should give me undefined error as the filter operation is asynchronous and returns promise.
But it is rather working fine.
Does that mean filter function is not returning promise but acting in synchronous way.
Please clarify as i am new in this coding.

```
this.deleteRTI = function(rtiName, operationName){
        let str = rtiName +' [Rule Template Instance]'
        console.log(str)
        let requiredArtifacts  = this.listProjectsArtifacts.filter(function(element,index) {
            return element.getText().then(function(text){               
                return text === str;
            })
        }).first();
        let loc = requiredArtifacts.getLocation();
         browser.actions().mouseMove(loc).perform();
         browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).perform();
         this.rightClickOperationsOnArtifacts('Delete')
         this.confirmDeleteArtifacts.click()
         return this.deployToastMessage.getText().then(function(text){
             return text;
         })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see the documentation of `filter` [here](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter), it clearly mentions that it returns `ElementArrayFinder`.

This `filter` is different from the `filter` which is supported on arrays. That filter doesn't work with promises while the protractor filter method can either return a boolean or a promise that resolves to a boolean.